# How can I change the lighted area on my restaurants refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

I'd like to change the area that's lit up on this refrigerator so it has my coffee shop logo:  https://www.restaurantsupplydrop.com/collections/refrigeration-units/products/atosa-bottom-mount-two-section-sliding-glass-door-reach-in-refrigerator-mcf8709

I want to put my business' information on it, this way it's not advertising the manufacturer.

Comment: Contact a sign company that makes back lit signs.  This isn’t a DIY Home Improvement question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a commercial signage question.

Comment: `How can I change the lighted area on my restaurants refrigerator?` ... remove the existing one and install a replacement

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to do that, and it's simple signmaking.  Like when you buy a picture frame in walmart and it has a picture already in it, that's for display purposes.   It can help to rent the cooler from Pepsi or Coke, then you'll get a mandatory Pepsi or Coke logo up there, but they'll help bigtime with the cost of the cooler.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact either the manufacturer or a company that make back lit signs, since the panel comes with that design already and putting something in front will only block the light.